# Selecting elements by specific Class Name

Tags: python, selenium, classname

I would like to select elements by the class name, but only with a specific name`(first-level-li)`, if there are other classes with the name that I am trying to select but followed for other names

```
(<li class="first-level-li no-second-level shop-link">
<li class="first-level-li  no-second-level  ">)
```

, I need to ignore them, how can I do this?
Example:

```
firstLevelMenu = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name ( "first-level-li" )
```

website

```
<li class="first-level-li no-second-level shop-link">
<li class="first-level-li  no-second-level  ">
<li class="first-level-li  ">
```

Comment: you can select with xpath

Comment: unfortunately, using by xpath (find_elements_by_xpath) is not returning any elements, and there are 9 elements in the page. Do you know the reason?

Comment: print len(firstLevelMenu)

Comment: What is the url?

Comment: @SDB in the example html you gave, the class name has 2 spaces after it. So your xpath to match that would actually be with the 2 spaces ("//li[@class='first-level-li  ']").  It has to match exactly

Comment: perfect, you are correct!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
firstlevelMenu = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='first-level-li  ']")
```

Docs are here http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: unfortunately, using by xpath (find_elements_by_xpath) is not returning any elements, and there are 9 elements in the page. Do you know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath to do the same:

```
self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='first-level-li']")
```

This finds the element that has the exact class name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath as mentioned above with following function too which will directly return object of specific element, instead of list.

self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='first-level-li ']")